# Asp.net mvc 4 - Need to use sessions but can't use cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookieless

I am working on an **ASP.NET MVC 4** application.

I need to use the session for storing various things. My mandate is to not use cookies.

Is there a way I can work through this? I have been told that ASP.NET MVC 4 will not work in cookie-less mode.

Is there any other alternative way?

Comment: MVC 4 will most certainly work without cookies. So long as you don't use them. And Session support hasn't changed at all in MVC 4.

Comment: I was under the impression MVC does not support cookieless sessions?  If you create a test project with cookieless sessions enable in the web.config everything seems to work okay.  But then try and create a simple ActionLink and it goes horribly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your web.config

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" timeout="20" />
```

Comment: There is also a line in the FormsAuthenticationService, in the SignIn() method that writes to a cookie. How do we deal with that?

Comment: Its related to the original question, your accepted answer above does not address both issues for cookieless mvc apps, your answer is only a partial answer.

Comment: I understand, I will ask another question. But do know that if his mandate was to be truly cookieless, this answer doesn't address the "other" cookie that gets created upon login.

Comment: "My mandate is to not use cookies.", I assumed that meant ALL cookies, my apologies if that was presumptuous of me.