# ASP.NET Sessions and browser cookie support

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using ASP.Net session and want to know what the behaviour will be when the user browser does not support cookies. I have tested this on a prototype where I blocked third party cookies and its was storing values in session and i was able to retrieve it. Can anyone clarify?

Poornima

Comment: What browser are you using that doesn't support cookies? Unless you have cookieless sessions enabled, your scenario is impossible.

Comment: The session ID cookie won't be a third-party cookie. The domain of the cookie will match the domain of the page which sets it, making it a first-party cookie.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [ASP.NET MVC and using cookieless sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638446/asp-net-mvc-and-using-cookieless-sessions), cookieless sessions are not supported by ASP.NET anymore. There used to be a cookieless session mode (which worked by rewriting the URL, see e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)), but this seems to be deprecated.